# Incorrect cell data when scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reuseidentifier

I have a UITableView, which cells are UICollectionViews(a horizontal slider). Each UITableViewCell contains vary number of items. For example, the first row of the UITableView contains 3 pictures, the second row contains 2 pictures, and the third row contains 1 pictures, and so on. My data source looks like this

```
 `[
   [item1, item2, item3],
   [item1,item2], 
   [item1]
   [item1, item2, item3],
   [item1,item2], 
   [item1]
 ]`
```

after scrolling back and forth, it may looks like this

```
`[
   [item1, item2, item3],
   [item1,item2], 
   [item1,item2]
   [item1, item2],
   [item1,item2], 
   [item1]
 ]`
```

I researched and found out that I may need to override the prepareForReuse method in my custom class which subclass UITableViewCell as suggested here

[ios uitableview uitableviewcell reuse has old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440728/ios-uitableview-uitableviewcell-reuse-has-old-data)

In my custom UITableViewCell, I have a UICollectionView as my property. I wonder how should I reset the entire UICollectionView, or am I heading to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I can use `collectionView.reloadData` inside `prepareForReuse` method, and the cell in the tableView will remain updated