# UITableViewCell selected buttons change to unselected state upon scroll the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The button action is `SongsSelectionSongs_Click`. When I click this button, the button image changing, the button tap count is getting correct and after selected button images also changing, but when I scroll back and forth in the `UITableView` the button image seems to be randomly changing.

[image]

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SongsTAbleViewCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SongsTAbleViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    btn_songSelect.tag = indexPath.row;
    lbl_songLabel.text = [[arr_tablVArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SongTitle"];
    lbl_artistLabel.text = [[arr_tablVArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SongArtist"];

    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)SongsSelectionSongs_Click:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    CGPoint correctedPoint = [button convertPoint:button.bounds.origin toView:self.tblv_SongslisttableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblv_SongslisttableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:correctedPoint];
    NSLog(@"Button tapped in row %d",indexPath.row);

    SelectedAlbumUrl = [[arr_tablVArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SongUrl"];
    str_songtitle = [[arr_tablVArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SongTitle"];

    if ([[button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"]])
    {
        btn_songsShareButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [btn_songSelect setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"remove.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonStatus = buttonStatus +1;
        [btn_songsShareButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    else
    {
        [btn_songSelect setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonStatus = 1;
        [btn_songsShareButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Try It, it's Working Fine

## pragma .h File

```
NSMutableArray * rowIdArray;
```

## pragma .M File

```
@synthesize rowIdArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    rowIdArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  }

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
   return 1;
 }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
   return [NamesArray count];
 }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   ViewControllerCell *cell = (ViewControllerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if(cell == nil)
     {
        NSArray *nib;
        nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewControllerCell" owner:self options:nil];


        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
     }
// Configure the cell...
  cell.nameslbl.text = [NamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  cell.nameBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
  [cell.nameBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(NamesClick_Tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   NSString *a=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
   NSString *b=[[NSString alloc]init];

  for (int i=0;i<[rowIdArray count];i++)
   {
       b=[rowIdArray  objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([a isEqualToString:b])
         {

           UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_selected.png"];
           [cell.nameBtn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          }

       }

      return cell;
}

-(IBAction)NamesClick_Tapped:(id)sender
  {

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.NameTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.NameTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    NSString *rowIdStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

    if(![rowIdArray containsObject:rowIdStr])
     {

       [rowIdArray addObject:rowIdStr];

     }else{

      [rowIdArray removeObject: rowIdStr];

     }
    [self.NameTableView reloadData];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything within your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to select or deselect image. When you reuse a cell, it doesn't change the state of the cell unless you explicitly tell it to in `cellForRow`. Therefore, it will either reuse a selected or deselected cell (whatever is the first available reusable cell) and put that on the screen as-is.

To fix this issue, you need logic in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to either select or deselect the image based on what is appropriate.

---

In general, if your problem has anything to do with "my cells don't show up right when scrolling" odds are you're not reusing your cells properly.

**EDIT:** in response to your comment, *no*, I will not rewrite your code. But I *will* give you some direction.

I would recommend keeping an additional key/value on your `arr_tablVArray` that will track whether or not the "share" should be enabled or disabled (I would suggest a `bool` value). This would make it so that you could check whether or not the "share" is enabled/disabled by checking a `bool` instead of checking the contents of the button's image in your `IBAction` method.

This info would now be available in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method as well, and you could check the value for the current record in `arr_tablVArray` and set your images accordingly just like you set your `lbl_songLabel` and `lbl_artistLabel`.

Comment: Thanks for replaying.Can you edit my code ,what we have to write cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @user2318392 I have edited my post to give you additional information.

Answer (score 0):

when you reuse a cell where the button has been already set, the same button appears with the previously set image. Instead of creating a new button every time you need a cell, you should just be resetting the state of an existing button. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369088/how-do-i-clear-a-cell-completely-when-i-reuse-it/9369190#9369190) might help you.